# AWS CloudWatch is charging me without using

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms, aws-billing

Recently i discovered my bill raising without using anything above free tier of with very minor charges.
On the bill management page it was clear that the charges are coming from CloudWatch Alarms as you can see in the picture below.

My question is why and how can i stop them? I can see that the alarms are been created by DynamoDB
auto-scaling, but i can't continue being charged for such a simple thing, i'm sure there is an option to disable it but i can't figure out.

*Edited* I checked "hide auto-scaling alarms" box but i think it's not the fix, fingers crossed to be:P

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

This is part of DynamoDB AutoScaling. For a small project, you should consider using DynamoDB without Provisionned Throughput.

Comment: I'm really start to get crazy about this thing. It continues raising the balance without even using a single metric, also it says that i have 10.000 alarms on Virginia where i don't even use. On cloudwatch alarm page i can't see anything. Please help:(

Answer (score 0):

AWS Free Tier [includes](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/) 10 Alarm metrics (not applicable to high-resolution alarms).

See [How can I determine why I was charged for CloudWatch usage, and then how can I reduce future charges?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-understand-and-reduce-charges/)

Comment: I'm really start to get crazy about this thing. It continues raising the balance without even using a single metric, also it says that i have 10.000 alarms on Virginia where i don't even use. On cloudwatch alarm page i can't see anything. Please help:(

Comment: You can permanently delete alarms that you know you will never need.